# Regex in scanner only finds first match

Tags: java, regex, parsing, java.util.scanner

I have a text file containing a number of articles which I need to parse through.

I need to retrieve every single word in each article, excluding any full stops, commas, etc. The articles are separated by a specific two lines, and I'm trying to use a regex pattern to find these points.

An example of the document is as follows:

```
.I 1
.W
this is article one.         
.I 2
.W
this is article two.                   
.I 3
.W
this is article three.
```

The code below seems to find the first occurrence `.I 1` and add all subsequent words, but once it gets to the next separator it adds it as a word instead of skipping it.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(document);
scanner.useDelimiter("[^\\w']+");
String separator;
while (scanner.hasNext()){
    separator = scanner.findInLine(Pattern.compile(".I \\d"));
    if (separator!= null) {
        System.out.println("Found: " + separator);
        scanner.nextLine();
        scanner.nextLine();
    }
    list.add(scanner.next());
}
scanner.close();
```

If possible I'd also like to be able grab the actual article number, which is the number attached to each separator.

What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that since you tell the `Scanner` to use everything except word characters and ticks as delimiters, the dot in front of `I` is consumed by `scanner.next()` each time it is about to come up in your `findInLine` search.

You can fix this by reading input by line instead of reading it by word, like this:

```
list.add(scanner.nextLine());
```

To get article number, parse the delimiter starting at character 3:

```
int num = Integer.valueOf(separator.substring(3));
```

Here is a demo that reads from standard input:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
scanner.useDelimiter("[^\\w']+");
String separator;
Pattern rx = Pattern.compile(".I \\d");
while (scanner.hasNext()){
    separator = scanner.findInLine(rx);
    if (separator!= null) {
        int num = Integer.valueOf(separator.substring(3));
        System.out.println("Found: " + separator+", article number: "+num);
        scanner.nextLine();
        scanner.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
}
scanner.close();
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/AopsBZ)

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using a variant of this, by not using that delimiter with scanner. Once I had each line I used String.split with the original delimiter regex to get each individual word.